# Как добавить текст из HTML страницы в базу данных?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Есть форма с текстом и счетчик символов, как добавить текст из формы и значение счетчика в базу данных.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как данные из формы я вроде догадываюсь, из метода _POST можно выдернуть, а вот как из счетчика я понятия не имею.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cyberpunk3351/zhpgwsux/4/)

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="text-center"><textarea id="textarea" class="form-control"></textarea></p>
    <p class="text-center">Кол-во символов – <span class="text-success" id="result2"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: зачем счетчик добавлять, это ж просто длина текста; где надо -- берете длину и показываете

Comment: Мне нужно создать таблицу в базе данных где будет хранится, текст формы, и количество символов. Данные должны браться именно из HTML странницы

Answer (score 1):

Если данные должны браться из HTML странницы, то сделайте счетчик `input`-ом, `disabled`, чтоб не редактировался, и напишите css, чтоб выглядел как сейчас.

Вообще, задание звучит, как неправильное, т. к. из содержимого сообщения можно вывести количество символов, и не за чем увеличивать избыточность информации.